# Iterable has value but when i try to pass it in functions or convert it to list it appears to be null

Tags: flutter, dart, future, iterable

I have a `Future` that returns a value of type `Iterable<Contact>` from the Flutter plugin contacts-service.
My code is like this:

```
var contacts = await ContactsService.getContacts();
```

But if I try to print it for example it throws an exception that the input cannot be null.
The same happens if I try to run `.toList().`

But as you can clearly see in the following picture the object has data.
[image: Picture containing the error but also the data of the object]

I'm really stuck and I'd appreciate the help.

Comment: Please add the code for methode ``ContactsService.getContacts()``

Comment: @Tidder The code is from a plugin that used to work like 2 days ago.
https://pub.dev/packages/contacts_service#-readme-tab-

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in the readme. Things like permissions and editing the manifest and plist files?

Comment: @sudo_kaizen all the steps about the permissions have been followed correctly. The code worked 2 days ago. For some reason, it stopped working now. That's the most frustrating part. And the thing is that it returns what it's supposed to return. But the compiler sees it as null. Never happened to me before

Comment: I'm trying to replicate your code right now

Comment: Do you have a TextField anywhere in your app? I just replicated tour code and it is working fine

Comment: @sudo_kaizen I do. But it's in another widget. Like I have an inherited widget and a textfield is one of those children and then a contract list is another widget that inherits from parent

Answer (score 0):

To whoever comes to this thread looking for the answer.

I made an issue to the flutter repo, they told me to make an issue to the library that I was using.

I made an issue to the library repo, they told me it works just fine when finally another person had the exact problem. The issue in the library is now closed and a google employee that I'm following on github made a null-safety-test. So you're not crazy after all. It's just a bug. A rare one, but a bug none the less!